# how can i retrieve multilevel data in firebase database --Webapp

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications

i'm new to firebase and i'm trying to create a wallpaper app. i want to retrieve the data from database which look like this.
[image]

. but it's more than two  levels. i want to show the details of boygroup and girlgroup but not their name. i want to show like this 
[image]

i can do what i want if i dont add level boygroup and girlgroup but i need these for a categories.it's three level values and it's confusing me how to retrieve boy group child and same with girl group child in one go.
this is the code for two level childs.. please help me

```
var dbCategories = firebase.database().ref("categories");
    dbCategories.on("value",function(categories){`


        if (categories.exists()) {
            var categorieshtml = "";

            categories.forEach( function(category) {
                // statements

                var newCategory =category.val();
                console.log(category);
                categorieshtml += "<tr>";

                //for category name 
                categorieshtml += "<td>";
                categorieshtml += category.key;
                console.log(categorieshtml);
                categorieshtml += "</td>";

                //for category Description

                categorieshtml += "<td>";
                categorieshtml += category.val().desc;
                console.log(categorieshtml);

                categorieshtml += "</td>";              

                //for category Thumbnail

                categorieshtml += "<td> <img width='250' height='150' src='";
                categorieshtml += category.val().thumbnail;
                categorieshtml += "'/></td>";
                categorieshtml += "</tr>";

            }); 

            $("#categories").html(categorieshtml);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
const dbCatagoriesRef = firebase.database.ref('categories')
dbCatagoriesRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    const dbCatagories = snapshot.val();
    const bodyGroupCategory = dbCatagories.bodygroup;
    const girlGroupCategory = dbCatagories.girlgroup;

    // es6
    Object.values(bodyGroupCategory).forEach(wallpapper) {
        // Do with what is needed with the wallpapper
        console.log(wallpapper.thubmnail)
    }

    // can also do the same to girlGroupCategory 
})
```

However while this how you do it ... You should not do it... You should only listen for changes on the smallest tree that you can... listening for value - or other firebase changes - on locations at the top of the tree (document/object) will put more strain on your DB, and with high loads of data, this can even Make your whole firebase DB get stuck.

Comment: Hi thank you i! i wanted to show both categories details on a web page. should i remove the sub category boy group and girl group in order to less the strain on DB?

Comment: Yes you should for many reasons ... 1) You pay for bandwidth for firebase, you don't want to load data that is not needed on a regular basis
2) Attaching firebase on A large document with many nested children will cause slowness in your app performance
3) If you attach a listener on for example the root of your document, and you have a lot of data there, firebase can get stuck for all your applicationhttps://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
You can read firebase recommendation here